# How to route user to particular div with Vue + Typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js

I've been trying to figure out how to link a Vue component and a div with a particular id inside of it, so that the user clicks the "Service" button and gets redirected to the home page, but autoscrolls to the "services" div. Is there any way I can do this?

This is my `index.ts` router file:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomePage from '../pages/Home.vue'
import TransportationPage from '../pages/Transportation.vue'
import DistributionPage from '../pages/Distribution.vue'
import WineAndSpiritsPage from '../pages/WineAndSpirits.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomePage,
    },
    {
      path: '/transportation',
      name: 'transportation',
      component: TransportationPage,
    },
    {
      path: '/distribution',
      name: 'distribution',
      component: DistributionPage,
    },
    {
      path: '/wineandspirits',
      name: 'wineandspirits',
      component: WineAndSpiritsPage,
    },
  ],
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition){
    //always scroll to top when a page is loaded
    return{top:0}
  },
})

export default router
```

I'm fairly new to typescript and the router itself, so sorry if this is easy to solve.

I used a simple `onclick` function on the buttons I tried to make work, but when I'm in another page (aka another Vue component) they just don't work.

Example:

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <a
            onclick="document.getElementById('contact').scrollIntoView();"
              class="nav-link"
              >Contact</a
            >
          </li>
```

I wanted to do something like this, if possible:

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <a
            to="/contact"
              class="nav-link"
              >Contact</a
            >
          </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use `router.push` for that, with the `hash` attribute:

```
router.push({ name: 'distribution', hash: '#contact' });
```

[See docs.](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location)

In your template you can use the `routerLink` component:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'distribution', hash: '#contact' }">Contact</router-link>
```